# Clear Instruction about SVN Path Options

Tags: macos, svn, osx-lion, svn-server

I've been working for a while now trying to understand SVN better. I am working with a Mac OSX Lion server. I've been able to set up and getting a SVN running on the machine and make it so I can check in and out documents. However, I want to make it accessible to additional services over the internet,so while many of my colleagues and I are traveling, we can still work in conjunction. I have forwarded port 3690 (I believe that's the SVN port) and the port for ssh was set up previously.

I installed the SVN Repository at `/Library/Subversion/Repository/`, and I have Versions and Terminal on the server to test with. I can connect by using the `file://` path parameter but I can not connect using `svn+ssh://username@localhost/MyProject`.

I know for a fact that I can connect through ssh and the error is "No repository found". I'm guessing I need a different path, but all the Mac OS articles I've read only tell how to set it up on the host not for use over LAN or externally.

Any ideas or thoughts are greatly appreciated. As a reference to the steps I've taken below are some of the links to articles I was working from.

- http://www.midwinter-dg.com/permalink-how_to_use_subversion_version_control_with_coda_on_the_mac_2010-11-18.html
- http://www.rubyrobot.org/tutorial/subversion-with-mac-os-x
- http://svn-ref.assembla.com/subversion-server-guide-mac-os.html

Comment: Try first to log in manually to 
ssh username@localhost . Then you should be able to check out the repositories with url 
/Library/Subversion/Repository/MyProject

Comment: Yeah, I can if I log on using terminal through ssh first and use the command line tool or versions to access the files directly on the server it works fine but if I do as above I get the error "No repository found", why would this be?

Comment: I understand ssh works and the files are at that path. What I also mean is that you must use that full local path when you svn co .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, make sure that your Mac firewall isn't blocking you. Can you remotely log in via `ssh` from another system to your system? If not, go to *System Preferences*, select the *Security and Privacy* preference, then select *Firewall*. You'll need to click the *Advanced...* button.

Once there, make sure *Remote Login (SSH)* is active through the Firewall.

Once you've allowed `ssh` access to your Mac, you'll need to make sure that you have `svn+ssh` setup correctly. Try from your own Mac to access the repository via `svn+ssh://` and not via `file://`. If you can't do that, you don't have `svn+ssh` setup correctly.

Setting up Subversion to use `svn+ssh` is the trickiest of the four ways to access a Subversion repository. Unlike `svn://` and `http://`, the repository server isn't running until the user logs into your system.

When a user connects vis `svn+ssh`, they immediately start up `svnserve` in order to access the Subversion repository (that's the `svn` part of `svn+ssh`).

Because `svnserve` runs as the user who used `ssh` to access the repository, each directory and file created in the physical repository directory will be owned by that user. Thus, you need to make sure that all users who have access to that repository are in the same primary group, **and** any created files or directories in the Subversion repository directory are read/writeable by that group.

In order to ensure that, you need to take the following steps:

- Make sure all Mac users who have access to your Subversion repository have the same primary group. You create a group in your Mac using the *Users and Groups* preference pane. Click on the *+* as when you're creating a new user, but select *Group* from the Drop down list. Put everyone who is going to log on in this group.
- When you create the Subversion repository

  - Make sure that all files and directories the repository directory tree are *owned* by the Subversion group via the `chgrp` command.
  - Use the `chmod` command to make sure the entire directory tree are read/writeable by that Subversion group.
- You need to set each user's `umask` to `002` or `0002` instead of the default `022` or `0022`. This way, when the user creates a new directory or file in the repository, it can be read and written by any other user in the group. Otherwise, one user will create a change, but other users won't be able to make modifications.

Take a look at these links from the on line [Subversion manual](http://svnbook.red-bean.com):

- [SSH Configuration Tricks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.sshtricks)
- [Svnserve and Tunneling Over SSH](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.svnserve.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve.sshtricks).

Comment: OP: Apache with ssl and svn modules are much easier to get working imho. But I could not find a good instruction for Mac OS. Try one targeting Linux.

Comment: @JohanLundberg The Subversion and SSL modules are already in Apache on Mac OS X. You just have to configure it by following the svnbook.com manual. It's actually pretty simple. The daemon is in `/usr/sbin/httpd`, the configuration file is in `/private/etc/apache2`, and the modules are in `/usr/libexec/apache2`.

Comment: You said the trickiest of 4 ways but in my searches and the tutorials I found I only heard mention of two, svn+ssh and apache with modules, so what are the other two ways?

Comment: @ars265 In order from easiest to hardest to setup: There's `file://` (which really shouldn't count since there's no server behind it.), there's `svn://`, there's `http://` & `https://`, and there's `svn+ssh://`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I'm adding another answer...

You might want to try a third party server like [Assembla](https://www.assembla.com/one_page_signup/free-private-subversion-repository-only) instead of trying it on your Mac. This will give everyone access without making your personal machine a server that needs to be up 24/7/365.

Comment: I had looked in to this as an alternative but we were really hoping to get our own server up and running svn although I have my doubts whether it should be the same server that we do all out development testing on.